# venv activate has no effect

Tags: python-3.x, virtual-environment

I want to use a virtualenv for my python3 project:
did `virtualenv -p python3 venv` to install it.
when doing `. venv/bin/activate`it doesn't activate the venv (I'm able to use all my lib's in standard path)  also no `(venv)` before prompt. There is also no error,  it just gives me a new line.
`source venv/bin/activate` gives me the same result.

Interestingly my VSCode detects when  `virtualenv -p python3 venv` is run and asks if I want to change the environment.

Comment: What does `source venv/bin/activate; echo $VIRTUALENV` print?

Comment: just a blank line

Comment: Looks like your virtualenv doesn't work at all; try recreating it (by deleting the folder `venv` and creating a new virtualenv there). What platform (Windows/Linux/Mac) are you on?

Comment: platform is MacOS 10.15, sorry forgot to mention that. recreated it; same results.

Comment: Do you get the same results with Python's builtin venvs? (`rm -rf venv; python3 -m venv venv; . venv/bin/activate`)

Comment: yes, nothing changed